# How to get record in text box on change select option in HTML_QuickForm for PHP

Tags: php

When user will select Customer Name then i want to fill Address & city of that customer at run time from the database.for that i am calling javascript function on change and from that i am calling php function addfun() and trying to pass from and keyvalue for query.  I write below code but thats not working.

```
    <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
function ILovePHP(frm, a) {
var formName = frm.name;  
    alert(formName);  
b=<?php addfun(formName,a);?>;  

alert(b);
}
</script>

    <?php 

 $attrs = array("onChange" =>    "ILovePHP(this.form, this.value);");   


require_once "HTML/QuickForm.php";
require_once "HTML/QuickForm/Renderer.php";
  $form = new HTML_QuickForm('customer_master', 'post');  

  $form->addElement('select','custName','Select Customer Name',$cnameAry,$attrs);  
  $form->addElement('text', 'custAdd', 'Customer Address');  
  $form->addElement('text','custCity', 'City'); 
  $form->addElement('text','custState', 'State');  

  $form->display();

  function addfun($frm, $p)
{

$query="Select  Address, City  from entityMaster where eid=$p ";


$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('GenInsurance');
$result=mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$frm->setDefaults(array( 'custAdd'   => $row['Address'])); 
$frm->setDefaults(array( 'custCity'   => $row['Address'])); 

print $frm;
return $frm;
}

?>
```

Comment: That won't work!
The PHP code is interpreted from the server, JS from the client. If you want to call a PHP function out of PHP then you need a HTTP-Request (search for Ajax)

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery and ajax to get the address and city from the php file:

create a file called ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['name']))
{

$p = $_GET['name'];

$query="SELECT Address, City FROM entityMaster WHERE eid=$p ";

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); 
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('GenInsurance');
$result=mysql_query($query);

$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$output = array('custAdd' => $row['Address'], 'custCity' => $row['Address']);

echo json_encode($output);

}
```

Onchange get the city and address:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
$('#custName').change(function(){

    $.getJSON("ajax.php", { name: $(this).val() } , function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if(key == "custCity"){
                $('#custCity').val(value);
                }
                if(key == "custAdd"){
                $('#custAdd').val(value);
                }   

        });
    });
});
```

Please read more on [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Ajax) and [jquery](http://www.jquery.com).